# SAS yyyymmdd to last date of month

Tags: sas

I updates the yyyymmdd variable e.g. 20141123 manually. 
and transforms 20141123 to 23NOV2014. I face some problem when I try to find the last day of the month which is 30NOV2014 and store it as enddate. My approach is using intnx(). While

```
data _null_;
    format yyyymmdd $8.;
    yyyymmdd = '20141123';

    yyyy = put(substr(yyyymmdd, 1, 4), $4.);
    yy = put(substr(yyyymmdd, 3, 2), $2.);
    mm = put(substr(yyyymmdd, 5, 2), $2.);
    dd = put(substr(yyyymmdd, 7, 2), $2.);

    date = put(mdy(mm, dd, yyyy), date9.);

    enddate = put(intnx('month',date,1,'end'), date9.);
run;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could read the yyyymmdd easier with an informat instead of using the substring/mdy conversion. Date=input(yyyymmdd,YYMMDD.);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things.

1. input() converts characters to numeric.
2. You are forcing SAS to convert characters of YYYY, MM, DD, and date to numeric variables.  I'm sure you saw the NOTES to that effect in the LOG.
3. You are getting the last day of the next month.  Current + 1.  You want Current + 0.

Try this

```
data _null_;
format yyyymmdd $8.;
yyyymmdd = '20141123';

yyyy = input(substr(yyyymmdd, 1, 4), $4.);
yy = input(substr(yyyymmdd, 3, 2), $2.);
mm = input(substr(yyyymmdd, 5, 2), $2.);
dd = put(substr(yyyymmdd, 7, 2), $2.);

date = mdy(mm, dd, yyyy);

put date date9.;
enddate = put(intnx('month',date,0,'end'), date9.);
put enddate;
run;
```

Comment: Hi @DomPazz. Thanks for your clear answer. My situation is that as i needa use date for further usage to export as filename like report&date..xls. (report23Nov2014.xls) While this code is numeric instead of date9. format. I should make another variable say dateoutput = put(date, date9.) to achieve that? or there is alternative method?

Comment: As i am new to sas and would like to clearify that date is numeric or character? Or it depends? If i do put(date, date9.) then it will transform from numeric to character? Thanks again for your gentle help.

Comment: Yes, `put(date, date9.)`, converts the numeric variable `date` to character (e.g. 21NOV2014, 18JUN1933, 19SEP2104)

Comment: A SAS date is always numeric, e.g. today is 20051. You can format a date to be more descriptive by applying a date format, e.g. date9. The underlying value is still numeric, but it's displayed in text form. When you use a `put()` statement, you're explicitly converting it from numeric to character, and it's no longer a date, it's a character string which represents a date.